# ADXL345 Accelerometer data output conversion

Tags: python, accelerometer

I'm using a Synapse wireless module which has a ATMEL ATmega128 on it. I've connected a ADXL345 3 axis accelerometer to it and I'm communicating with it via I2C. The Synapse module uses a subset of python as the scripting language.

When I read the XYZ data I get back an array of 6 bytes. 
EC FF EF FF 14 01

The output data is twos complement with DATAx0 as the least significant byte and DATAx1 as the most significant byte. So in the example above, EC FF is the output for the x axis.

I'm struggling with how to convert this into G force. The datasheet says in full resolution mode (which I'm in) the output resolution increases with the g range
set by the range bits to maintain a 4 mg/LSB scale factor.

I've tried the following:

```
x0 = ord(data[0])
x1 = ord(data[1])
raw = x0+(256*x1)
```

but the value of raw doesn't make any sense. How do I convert these two bytes into a signed integer?

**Additional Information**
When I make the call to read the adxl345:

```
data = readAdxls(6)
```

it returns the string of bytes read back from the external I2C device.

```
Xlsb = data[0] # EC - 236
Xmsb = data[1] # FF - 255
Ylsb = data[2] # EF - 239
Ymsb = data[3] # FF - 255
Zlsb = data[4] # 14 - 20
Zmsb = data[5] # 01 - 1
```

So Xlsb is the least significant **byte** and Xmsb is the most significant **byte**. These are integers

I guess I just don't understand the twos complement and how to combine these 2 integers/bytes into a signed integer.

Comment: How complete is this subset? Can you use the `struct` module?

Comment: No, the struct module is not part of the language. FWIW, there is no support for floats either. It's designed to be extremely light weight.

Comment: I'm sorry but if the two byte are EC and FF, being the second the most significant, the correct order is FF EC.
Therefore, to convert you just need:
(most << 8 | least) 
This will give you the raw data, then multiply it for the choosen sensor resolution.
If you go for the max resolution, just multiply for 0.0039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with `ord()` there...  `ord(c)` takes `c`, a single character, and outputs its ASCII character code.

Either way, to convert a number whose representation is in two's complement to a signed integer in Python, one would do something like this:

```
def tc(val, bits):
    if val >= 2**(bits-1):
        return val - (2**bits)
    return val

>>> tc(0xECFF, 16)
-4865
```

Though as for how to actually call that function with your data, I'd need to see what your data looks like in Python.  What sort of numbers are you expecting to see for G-force?

Comment: I should have looked at ord() more closely. It explains why the result made no sense.

Comment: I ended up shifting the msb then AND the lsb. msb<<8|lsb
Then I called Adam's function. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: How come you're ORing the MSB onto the LSB?  Surely you want a simple `+`...?

Comment: The output from the device is 16 bits for each axis and they are stored in 2 eight bit registers. I should have said I shift the msbyte<<8 then OR the lsbyte.

Comment: Sure sure, but why are you ORing?  You could just add them.

Comment: Because all of the example code I've seen where people are interfacing with the adxl345 via I2C have done it that way...

Comment: I don't see a reason to.  ORing requires an extra mental step; one needs to shift into binary thinking mode and figure out what shifting something and ORing it does.  It's the same outcome, at what I bet is identical performance, but better readability, to use a `+`.

Comment: The ADXL345 use a 16bit data, split in two 8 bit register (each axes).
That means you need to glue togheter the data inside the first register (least significative) with the second register (most significative) that should, therefore be shifted to the left by 8 places and "ORed" togheter with the first register.

Comment: I understand that, but my point is it's the same functionality with likely no reasonable performance benefit, and added obfuscation, over using `+`.